# Recognize non-english words on Android

Tags: android, voice-recognition, openears

Is there any kind of API which is similar to OpenEars for Android. I have a project to recognize non-english words.

All I want is when I say Machan in I need same text as the output. Is this possible? I tried musicg and it seams that lib recognize whistles.

Comment: SpeechRecognizer  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html

Comment: That doesn't recognize the word machan for normal english and other languages this works perfect but what I'm looking is not dictionary words

Comment: OpenEars is based on pocketsphinx. Pocketsphinx is available on Android http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid